# Concatetate a list to a numpy array

Tags: python

This is a simple question. I am trying to concatenate a list to a numpy nd array, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
import numpy as np
t = list(range(2))
a = np.random.rand(2,4)

t = np.array(t)
result = np.concatenate(t,a)

>> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: np.random.rand(2,4) generate a 2 by 4 random array. Is that what you want? If so, what is the desired concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate an array of shape `(2,)` and an array of shape `(2, 4)` like this:

```
import numpy as np

t = list(range(2))
a = np.random.rand(2,4)
t = np.array(t)

result = np.hstack((t[:, None],a))

# array([[ 0.        ,  0.54789168,  0.60478776,  0.03923133,  0.51515207],
#        [ 1.        ,  0.52476824,  0.030079  ,  0.95157973,  0.99690973]])
```